# Graph/Chart tools for angular 2

Tags: angular

The chart/graph tools I was able to find for angular 2 are

- [*Zingchart*](https://www.zingchart.com/)
- [*ng2-charts*](http://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/)

Is there any other chart/graph tools for angular 2? Which is the best in terms of

1. Performance
2. Functionality
3. Size
4. Price

Comment: other options are - highcharts, primeNG charts and Google Charts

Comment: I would vouch for highcharts

Comment: Biased because I work for them, but ZingChart is great. It's renders fast, has more features than pretty much any other library, and is free with the watermark. We also have the best support team of any charting libraries. The engineers who build the ZingChart library also handle support. Good luck getting in touch with any developers at Highcharts if you run into any issues or need support.

Comment: I believe it is worth checking out [ngx-charts](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-charts). I don't know about performance but it has a lot o functionality, it is well documented and it is free.

Answer (score 6):

Angular2 (unlike Angular1) does not require Angular specific implementations, you are free to use any 3rd party libs and componentise them thus ng2 can take full advantage of jQuery libs and bind to them.

I have had recent experience with ChartJS, ChartJS2, HighCharts and D3JS.

D3JS is like jQuery but for charts only. It requires you to build a chart from scratch, define axis and everything. This makes it very time consuming to use (but provides extreme flexibility). Generally, you won't have the time to invest in D3. However, there are libraries that work with D3 to simplify the process such as C3.

If you want a quicker result go with Highcharts or ChartJS2. If you are willing to spend money HighCharts is the best option. It is very professional and robust. It allows you to produce mixed chart types - such as bar chart WITH line chart and stuff. Really handy.

Alternatively, ChartJS is cheap and cheerful but does the job. You are limited on chart types but its a freebie.

I have had success dynamically binding chart data with all three of these libs in Angular2 so its very possible. You will see a whole load of data bound chart implementations [on my GitHub](https://github.com/danday74).

(Most of the chart examples were done in Angular2 very early days so the code might not be the same these days but it gives you an idea how to approach dynamic data binding if you require this).